# delete Modal Blur effect after dismiss modal view

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, subview

Currently I'm working on a project with MapView which presents a modalView, when the user press a button.

The modalView uses the typical Blur effect of iOS 8.

problem is, i can present the Modelview with Blur effect, and can Dismiss it, but i can't remove the blur effect of the map.

Current code:

ViewController.m

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if  ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Set a alarm"]) {

        [self blurEffectMethod];

        AlarmViewController *modal = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"setAlarm"];
        modal.transitioningDelegate = self;
        modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
        [self presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil]

-(void)blurEffectMethod {
    UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
    blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
    UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;

    if (_radiusSlider.hidden == NO) {
        visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
        visualEffectView.frame = _mapView.bounds;
        [_mapView addSubview:visualEffectView];
        //Hide Bars & Slider
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        _toolBar.hidden = YES ;
        _radiusSlider.hidden= YES;
        _sliderIndicator.hidden = YES;
    }

}
```

ModelViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)dismisModal:(id)sender {
    [_audioPlayer stop];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

How do i delete the blur SubView from the mapView while dismiss the modalView?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i manage to get my modal blur to work!

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen

let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
nc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen

presentViewController(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here i'm using the .OverFullScreen flag on prepareForSegue. And on my viewControllers a blur UIVisualEffectView is set

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "LifeEventSegue" {
        if let nc = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
            nc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
            if let vi = nc.viewControllers.first as? UIViewController {
                vi.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
            }
        }
    }
}
```